# Capturing Data from a tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

There are hundreds of articles explaining how to set data to a tableview but I couldn't find any for getting data from it.

For example, if a have a tableview with 3 rows and in each row I have 3 textfields, what is the best way to get these textfields?

Xcode 61 doesn't let me to create static cells and if I create 3 prototype cells, it doesn't allow me to create 9 different textfields (so I could manage the info separately).

So I understand I have to create 3 textfields in a prototype cell and then differentiate each row, but how can I differentiate each row in the function "cellForRowAtIndexpath"?

I'd appreciate every other solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are trying to reach the textfields not the data  then you can do this by getting subviews of table view

Comment: thanks for your response, I solved with Divya's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `tag` value to `each textField` from your "cellForRowAtIndexpath".

```
cell.TextField.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Take one mutable array.

Now when you textfield delegate method call, you can update or capture textFields value in array according to tag, and use for further process. Some thing like below.

```
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if([array count] > textView.tag)
    {
        [array replaceObjectAtIndex:textView.tag withObject:textView.text];
    }
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if([array count] > textView.tag)
    {
        [array replaceObjectAtIndex:textView.tag withObject:textView.text];
    }
}
```

If you are not clear let me know.

Answer (score 0):

best way I know of; if you're adding subview like a textField would probably be to tag them with restorationIdentifiers.

I think there is also a method for tableView that has something to do with accessoryViewDidChange or something

or add a target for the field and use didPerFormAction: maybe..

how did you configure the cell when you added the text field?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed Divya's solution and it worked. :)